# How to create options in KSH script

Tags: unix, ksh

I am creating a KSH interface script that will call other scripts based on the users input. The other scripts are Encrypt and Decrypt. Each one of these scripts receive parameters. I have seen someone execute a script before using "-" + first letter of a script name before. How do I do this for my script? So for example if my script is called menu and the user typed in : `menu -e  *UserID Filename.txt*` the script would run and the encrypt script would be executed along with the associated parameters. So far my script takes in the encrypt/decrypt script option as a parameter. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#I want this parameter to become an 
action=$1

if [ $1 = "" ]
    then 
    print_message "Parameters not satisfied"

    exit 1 
fi 

#check for action commands

if [ $1 = "encrypt" ]
    then
    dest=$2
    fileName=$3
    ./Escript $dest $fileName
elif [ $1 = "decrypt" ]
    then
    outputF=$2
    encryptedF=$3
    ./Dscript $outputF $encryptedF
else 
    print "Parameters not satisfied. Please enter encrypt or decrypt plus-n arguments"

fi
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for good question, showing some thought on your part. It looks ok od to me as is. While `getargs` is the usual method for dealing with options prefixed with `-` chars, can't you just test `if [ $1 = "-encrypt" ] ; then` ... etc? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any kind of automatic way to turn a parameter into another script to run; what you're doing is pretty much how you would do it. Check the parameter, and based on the contents, run the two different scripts.

You can structure it somewhat more nicely using `case`, and you can pass the later parameters directly through to the other script using `"$@"`, with a `shift` to strip off the first parameter. Something like:

```
[ $# -ge 1 ] || (echo "Not enough parameters"; exit 1)

command=$1
shift
case $command in
    -e|--encrypt) ./escript "$@" ;;
    -d|--decrypt) ./dscript "$@" ;;
    *) echo "Unknown option $command"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

This also demonstrates how you can implement both short and long options, by providing two different strings to match against in a single case statement (`-e` and `--encrypt`), in case that's what you were asking about. You can also use globs, like `-e*)` to allow any option starting with `-e` such as `-e`, `-encrypt`, `-elephant`, though this may not be what you're looking for.